# My simple audio amplifier circuit does not work

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone

In previous experiments I've made circuits to transfer sound from electret microphone to a powered speaker. Now I'm doing my first experience with an Op-Amp to make the sound louder and to be able to hear it in a headphone. The Op-Amp I'm using is LM358N. Here is my circuit:

[image]

I'm using the formula below, that I copied from the Internet for the non-inverting operation amplifier:

$$Gain = 1 + \frac{R2}{R1}$$

Given the resistor values of **R1= 4.7 ohm , R2 = 150 ohm**, my gain is about 32.9 times.

So here is the summary of information about my circuit:

- V+ = 5v from USB
- Capacitor : 0.1uF
- R next to V+ : 4.7 Kohm
- R1= 4.7 ohm
- R2 = 150 ohm

But my speaker doesn't work when the op-amp IC is placed on the circuit. If the op-amp IC is inserted on it's socket, I can hear only "rett, rett" when I try to blow to the electret microphone. What is wrong here?

Comment: What op-amp are you using? And, more importantly, what is its output impedance? Also what is the impedance of your speaker?

Comment: @KGregory As i mentioned, the Op-Amp i'm using is LM358N. I don't know what is the impedance of my speaker and my headphone, i just buy it from store to listen to music, how can i know it ?

Comment: are you using + and - power supplies ( i.e. +15/-15) or is your op-amp single supply? If only single supply as you seem to be, you need to bias the op-amp so that output can handle the negative and positive from the microphone

Comment: @Marla As i mentioned, i'm using 5V DC power supply from USB. All of components in my circuit is plugged from one power supply source (USB 5v).

Comment: oops, i missed that. The speaker impedance is typically advertised on the package when you buy it. Most speakers are 4 or 8 ohms, but yours may be different.

Comment: Electret Microphone design: http://www.eevblog.com/2014/05/03/eevblog-611-electret-microphone-design/ - great intro!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem may be that the LM358 is not designed to drive a speaker as a load. You will need to add an output stage with a low output impedance of ~4 to 32 ohms or less, depending on your speaker's impedance. Here is an example of a typical configuration using BJTs as the output stage:

[image: speaker driver schematic]

Note how the feedback loop has been modified to incorporate the output stage. A trimpot is used in this schematic to adjust the volume.

My second hypothesis, is in the event that you have a high impedance set of headphones (around 600 ohms), is that your gain is too high and your are railing out. If that's the case, then you can either reduce your gain or replace your gain resistors with a trimpot and try adjusting the volume until it sounds better. If the "rett rett" sound you described is a loud sound, then I would recommend skipping my first suggestion and try this first instead.

Comment: any Biasing concerns with the LM358? using single supply

Comment: I don't think so, the 358 datasheet provides characterization data from single +5 supply. The speaker shouldn't care about the DC offset so long as your driver can push and pull current through it in both directions.

Comment: @KGegory . . so if microphone is at zero volts, the output is at zero volts. What happens when microphone is at -.1 volts ?

Comment: Well for one, his microphone won't go negative either because it is also single supplied. Secondly, he is AC coupled at the input through that blocking capacitor, so that would remove the DC component anyway.

Comment: I think I might run a simulator on this one  :)  . .

Comment: point being is that the positive input would be at an average of zero volts (if there were a 1M-ohm resistor from + to ground). Thus, the average output volts would be zero volts. No chance of reacting to the negative inputs from the microphone

Comment: You might be right, but I think the feedback path will bias the LM358's input up to somewhere around 2.5V.

Comment: if positive input is zero, then the feedback path must also provide zero volts to minus input.  ( I am trying not to be like grumpy Olin here,  being gentle in saying that biasing has to be done)

Comment: again, the DC component is removed by the blocking cap

Comment: I state that the positive input needs 2.5v bias. I will leave it up to others to conclude then. Good discussion here KGregory

Comment: @Marla I don't have both PNP and NPN transistor now so it's hard to test this circuit. I will try it later, anyway thank you so much.

Comment: try the bias that I suggested (takes 2 resistors). Maybe you can answer the question here :)   . .

Comment: Implementing the bias takes more than two resistors. You also have to decouple the inverting input from ground, via a large capacitor between the junction of the 1k resistor and 10k trimpot and ground, so that the inverting input can float up to the same DC potential as the non-inverting input.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to apply a 2.5 volt bias to the op-amp positive (+) INPUT terminal. You can use a resistor divider (something like 4.7K and 4.7K from positive to ground at your positive terminal.  This will cause the output to be at 2.5 volts when no signal is present at the microphone.

Also, you will need a capacitor in series with you speaker (headphone), perhaps 1 to 10 uf. This removes the DC bias from the headphone.

As it is, your amplifier is attempting to only amplify the positive values of the microphone.

Edited to say positive INPUT terminal.

Comment: Instead of 2.5v. I'm using the 3.2v source from the Arduino board. I connect 3.3v source directly to the op-amp VCC pin. I also connect 1uf capacitor between output and speaker. But still not working. No sound generated when i blow to the microphone

Comment: EDIT : Oh dear. I must have misled when I said the "positive terminal".  I should have said the positive input terminal. Corrected now on my answer.

Comment: Ok, i found that your solution can work only with "Inverting operation amplifier circuit". I don't know why it does not work with "Non-inverting operational amplifier circuit".

Answer (score 3):

You have a spare opamp, try doing this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhewaT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This creates a "virtual ground" at 2.5V. R3 and R4 divide your supply voltage to get 2.5V, OA3 buffers it so that R3 and R4 don't interfere with the gain setting resistors. Then you make this buffered voltage your "ground" reference point. The effect is the same as if you were powering the opamp with +-2.5V. R5 is there to tie the noninverting input to some voltage so that waveform from the input "rides" on 2.5V.

Your circuit works erratically, because noninverting input is essentially floating when there is no signal. When left floating it usually floats close to one of the rails and that gets amplified.

When you blow into the microphone, you inject some current into the input and make it swing to a region where the gain resistors and amplification makes sense, thus you hear some popping noise. If you would connect a 100K resistor from noninverting input to ground, you'd get more consistent output, just distorted, because only positive peaks from the input would be amplified as opamp would have no way to swing it's output below it's negative rail - 0V in your case.

Note that you probably will not be able to run a 8 ohm speater with LM385, more like small high impedance headphones. If you want to run a loud speaker, get yourself an LM386.